# Polling and consuming messages from Amazon SQS as a service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I am using a `SQS` as a 'bridge' in my system, which receives tasks from `GAE` and will be processed on the `EC2`. Currently, I am able to add tasks to this queue from GAE, but with some difficulties on how to consume these tasks on `EC2`. So my questions are:

1. What are the recommended ways of building a task consumer (python based) on `EC2`, which would keep an eye on `SQS` and assign new inbound jobs to works?
2. Does AWS has this type of `SQS` monitoring product? If not, is `Celery`'s `period task` a good candidate?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I'm also wondering this.

Answer (score 1):

The task consumer is just a (long) poller. The boto Python library has SQS support. AWS provides the SQS service, but they don't make the consumers. I'm not familiar with Celery.

Standard practice is to poll for message (which marks it as 'invisible'), and then perform action at consumer end. At action completion, delete message. If action fails because one of your compute nodes disappeared the message will become visible after a period of time and it'll be picked up in a future poll. If you need something smarter you may want to implement an external ESB or experiment with AWS SWF.

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/sqs.html

http://aws.amazon.com/swf/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will check the SWF out. But I am also open to any sqs monitoring system, which periodically poll the queue and fire workers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS Beanstalk service to consume the tasks in the Queue
[AWS Beanstalk with SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html)

If you don't want to breakdown your code to run within Beanstalk you can write some code for beanstalk to pull an item off the queue and then send it to your ec2 server, essentially making Beanstalk hand out the messages/tasks in the queue. This would remove the need for your ec2 server to constantly poll the queue